# border-radius with border more than 1px on select tag buggy in webkit

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit

Does anybody know a workaround for following 'bug' in webkit?

When I use `border-radius` and `border: solid 1px` to create rounded borders on select tag it just works fine on webkit, FF and so on

But when the `border` more than `1px` you can see the container's background overlapping the border.

You can see it here: http://dabblet.com/gist/2909020

(just change `border: solid 2px #9ec3d6;` to `1px` to see the difference)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is a bug in chrome, see here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=81556

Comment: thanks for your response Bjoern but if I set the outline:none the ugly rectangle border is still there

Comment: Well, since it is a bug, maybe use another way to archieve what you want (maybe a way outdated approach, but you could use a background image for this).

Answer (score 0):

With `-webkit-appearance: none;` you can hide the rectangle border, but this will also hide the usual dropdown icon of the select box, but you could add some background images to bring back some kind of visual indicator for the select box.

Look at these examples: http://37signals.com/svn/posts/2609-customizing-web-forms-with-css3-and-webkit

Comment: @HimawanDjaja Actually it would be only two lines of CSS: `-webkit-appearance: none;` and `background` (you could use data-uris).
I'm not aware of a simpler approach. Sorry

Comment: Yes, but its not compatible with firefox, because -moz-appearance: none has bug as you can see it here https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649849